# LoDash _.has for multiple keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

Is there a method or a chain of methods to check if an array of keys exists in an object available in lodash, rather than using the following?

```
var params = {...}
var isCompleteForm = true;
var requiredKeys = ['firstname', 'lastname', 'email']

for (var i in requiredKeys) {
    if (_.has(params, requiredKeys[i]) == false) {
        isCompleteForm = false;
        break;
    }
}

if (isCompleteForm) {
    // do something fun
}
```

**UPDATE**

Thanks everyone for the awesome solutions! If you're interested, here's the jsPerf of the different solutions.

http://jsperf.com/check-array-of-keys-for-object

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can totally go functional, with [`every`](https://lodash.com/docs#every), [`has`](https://lodash.com/docs#has) and [`partial`](https://lodash.com/docs#partial)functions, like this

```
var requiredKeys = ['firstname', 'lastname', 'email'],
    params = {
        "firstname": "thefourtheye",
        "lastname": "thefourtheye",
        "email": "NONE"
    };
console.log(_.every(requiredKeys, _.partial(_.has, params)));
// true
```

We pass a partial function object to `_.every`, which is actually `_.has` partially applied to `params` object. `_.every` will iterate `requiredKeys` array and pass the current value to the partial object, which will apply the current value to the partial `_.has` function and will return `true` or `false`. `_.every` will return `true` only if all the elements in the array returns `true` when passed to the function object. In the example I have shown above, since all the keys are in `params`, it returns `true`. Even if a single element is not present in that, it will return `false`.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this would be an ideal candidate for a [mixin](https://lodash.com/docs#mixin) if this was going to be reused regularly throughout an app.  It would also improve readability.  [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nwayve/9m9bcrtc/)

Answer (score 50):

I know the question is about lodash, but this can be done with vanilla JS, and it is much faster:

```
requiredKeys.every(function(k) { return k in params; })
```

and even cleaner in ES2015:

```
requiredKeys.every(k => k in params)
```

Comment: Note that the `in` operator [returns true for inherited properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in#Inherited_properties)

Comment: Also note that although the OP example mentions simple (i.e. direct) keys, lodash `_.has()` can handle complex, deep paths, e.g. `person[2].firstName` which will obviously not work with the example above.

Comment: is it possible to check nested props using this approach? eg. ```{a: {b: "c"}, b: "d"}``` here prop ```b``` is at root and under a. I want to check if b is there inside  a.

Answer (score 3):

```
_(requiredKeys).difference(_(params).keys().value()).empty()
```

I believe. The key step is getting everything into arrays then working with sets.

or

```
_requiredKeys.map(_.pluck(params).bind(_)).compact().empty()
```

Might work.

Comment: ```TypeError: _.pluck(...).bind is not a function.``` for the second solution

Comment: I believe _.pluck is now called _.map in lodash 4.15.0

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that params can have more properties than is required...

```
var keys = _.keys(params);
var isCompleteForm = requiredKeys.every(function (key) {
    return keys.indexOf(key) != -1;
});
```

Should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I wound up using a combo of some of the examples above.

```js
  properties.every(prop => has(obj, prop));
```

Since `has` in lodash fixes the `in` problem above, and it's still very readable, and to the point.